# alternative to Visual Studio for Editing VB.NET WebApp?

Tags: vb.net

So I've got a website thats been published to a web server using Visual Studio, compiled and all. And now i'd like to edit this website. I understand Visual Studio does some compiling and building include files before it is website ready. Is there any way to accomplish this outside of Visual Studio? I have long since given up my Windows setup with Visual Studio and now I really need to edit some of this code. Editing the source seems like no problem, but there are certain other things I'm having trouble with without Visual Studio (adding new public parent classes, for example). What are my options?

Comment: Create a virtual machine and install Windows on that. Then install the Visual Studio Express editions you need and use that to edit the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of .NET you are targeting [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) may help out here, also [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is a free IDE that will let you edit/compile VB.NET code